# Progress bar not updating during a loop

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

My progress bar doesn't update until the loop has finished? Why is this?

```
for (String theURL : IPArray) {
    URL url = new URL(theURL);
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
    String temp = address.toString();
    String IP = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("/") + 1, temp.length());
    URLArray.add(IP);
    Progress.percentage = (URLArray.size() * 100) / Progress.totalToDo;
    Progress.ipProgress.setString(Progress.percentage + "%");
    Progress.ipProgress.setValue(Progress.percentage);
    Progress.ipProgress.repaint();
    result += IP + System.getProperty("line.separator");
}
```

It will only update after it gets past the loop and not during it.

Comment: separate Thread maybe?

Comment: Yep, it's the same problem that gets asked twice a week. Please do search this site first to find your myriad solutions.

Comment: How about you help me or direct me to a post where I can find such answers instead of being ignorant.

Comment: Please look at the links to the right, such as [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271902/jprogressbar-wont-update)  ( check David Kroukamp's answer there) and [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094666/jprogressbar-wont-update?rq=1) (check MadProgrammer's answer there).

Comment: Maxim answered it for me, needed a new thread. Solved now thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed a new thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    String result = "";

    public void run() {
        for (String theURL : IPArray) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(theURL);
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
                String temp = address.toString();
                String IP = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("/") + 1, temp.length());
                URLArray.add(IP);
                Progress.percentage = (URLArray.size() * 100) / Progress.totalToDo;
                Progress.ipProgress.setString(Progress.percentage + "%");
                Progress.ipProgress.setValue(Progress.percentage);
                Progress.ipProgress.repaint();
                result += IP + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if ("www.".equals(e.getMessage())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            null, "Incorrect URL. Usage: http://www.URL.com\nError = Space! Can't use gaps in list.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }
        IPFrame.textAreaIP.setText(result);
        GEOLookup.check(IPFrame.textAreaIP.getText());
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: You may be interested in [[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)] official tutorial (especially about SwingWorker class). Also [[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java)] you have some info about this class.

Comment: will be works with setString & setValue wrapped into invokeLater, common and basic stuff for output from Runnable#Thread, reapint is very hard to already visible Swing GUI, ditry hack that invoked EDT from all corners, in compare with lightweight invokeLater